# Pyspark join getting failed on Dataproc

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run some python pyspark script on Dataproc cluster but getting failed with below error:

```
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 815, in join 
if isinstance(on[0], basestring): 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The syntax, I am using in my code is: -

```
df1.join(df2, col1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recreated my cluster using image=1.0(It means using spark1.6.2) and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L892), `on` is the "col1" argument you're passing in, and the code in Spark assumes that if `on is not None` that it definitely has at least one element. Is it possible that you're accidentally passing in an empty array for `col1`? Perhaps you can print out `col1` before calling `join` to make sure.

Comment: I need to look into it, but I am sure that I am not sending empty array there.